# Reduce space between button & images

Tags: html, css

I want to decrease space between "upload picture" button & "images" [square boxes] [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/fanbook)

Now its displaying like this :

[image]

I want like this :

[image]

```
.col1-layout .col-main {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
```

Comment: add margin-bottom:0 and margin-top:10px in #formId . That's it

Comment: Try to use margin and padding style to reduce space between button & images.

Comment: @Leothelion i updated your css, now i want to decrease some more space between button and image [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/fanbook)

Comment: @Leothelion thanks i got solution.

Comment: @NIKHILRANE Thansk for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unwanted character in html `-`

[image]

Remove it and adjust the margin here -

```
#formId {
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thansk for support.

Answer (score 1):

Use Top & Bottom Margin or Padding in Pixel

```css
#formId {
    margin: 15px auto 15px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thansk for support.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your CSS

```
#formId {
    margin: 3% auto 5%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

To

```
#formId {
    margin: 3% auto 0%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Also remove extra '-' that is there before ul.

Comment: Thansk for support.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your code if no need of it.

```
<div id="lblError" style="color:#ff0000;margin-top:10px;"></div>
```

and change below your css 3% to 0%

```
#formId {
margin: 3% auto 0%;}
```

Hope it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thansk for support.